# webpack --watch with skip initial build

Tags: webpack, watch

we're currently using webpack with the `--watch` flag.  It would be nice if there was a skip initial build flag similar to what is available with babel.  does anyone know if this is possible with webpack?

Comment: I was looking for something similar, but I solved it a bit different. I used a package called 'wait-on' to wait for the initial build to complete to trigger the next step.